# Prove that exist $M$ such that $\mathbb P(|X|\le M)=1$

Tags: probability

Let event $X$ such that $\mathbb E|X|^n \le 2008^n$ for $n=1,2,...$. Prove that exist $M$ such that $\mathbb P(|X|\le M)=1$

I have no idea how to use knowledge about $\mathbb E|X|^n \le 2008^n$ to get a thesis

Comment: Hi! do you mean $\mathbb E[|X|^n] \le 2008^n$ or $(\mathbb E[|X|])^n \le 2008^n$ ?

Comment: Another way is to notice that $P(|X| \geq M) = P(|X| = M) + P(|X|>M)$ and in order to the second term $=0$ the first (by MI) is upper-bounded by $(\frac{2008}{M})^n<1$ which is true for $M>2008$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $M=2009$. We will prove that $\Pr[|X| \leq  M] = 1$. Assume otherwise, i.e., that $\Pr[|X| > M] = \delta$ for some $\delta > 0$. Then by Markov's inequality:

$$\mathbb E[|X|^n] \geq M^n \Pr[|X|^n > M^n] = M^n \Pr[|X| > M]  = M^n \delta$$

But $M^n \delta = 2009^n \delta > 2008^n$ for $n$ large enough, thus leading to a contradiction and the required conclusion.

Comment: Is the first step a version of Markov inequality for $|X|^n$?

Comment: @Alex Yes exactly! I added an intermediate step.

Comment: It's even in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

A direct proof: Take any $M>2008$. For each $n$,
$$
P[|X|>M]= P[|X|^n>M^n]\le \frac{E[|X|^n]}{M^n}\le\frac{2008^n}{M^n}=\left(\frac{2008}M\right)^n.
$$
Since $2008<M$, the RHS tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. Conclude $P[|X|>M]=0$ and $P[|X|\le M]=1$.